# Transpose mysql key-value table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like that:

```
+------+---------+-------------+------+ 
| id   | key     | value       | user | 
+------+---------+-------------+------+ 
|    1 | first   | foo         | 32   | 
|    2 | second  | bar         | 32   | 
|    3 | system  | more        | 32   | 
|    4 | first   | galaxy      | 21   | 
|    5 | second  | foo         | 45   | 
|    6 | system  | other       | 45   | 
+------+---------+-------------+------+
```

and I need to transform that into:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+------+ 
| first     | second     | system  | user |
+-----------+------------+---------+------+ 
|   foo     | bar        | more    | 32   |
|   galaxy  | NULL       | NULL    | 21   |
|   NULL    | foo        | other   | 45   | 
+-----------+------------+---------+------+
```

It is ID is not used, *key* columns will be converted in colums, results will be grouped by user and non existing values will be set to NULL. Is that possible?

**EDIT**: I forget to say that *key* parameters are dynamic, not known in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO transposed_table (first, second, system, user)
SELECT t1.value, t2.value, t3.value, t1.user
FROM initial_table as t1
OUTER_JOIN initial_table as t2 ON t2.user = t1.user
OUTER_JOIN initial_table as t3 ON t3.user = t2.user;
```

Where I call `transposed_table` the newly targeted table and `initial_table` the one you already have.

Comment: The problem with this query is that you should know the keys in advance. The number and name of the keys is unknown